# How to show only those products on Website which have Quantity in Hand in Odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qwebview

I am new to Odoo. I want to show only those products on E-commerce Website which have quantity in hand greater than 0. I am using Odoo 10.

How can I do this?

My code is:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="hidden" id="products_grid_before"/>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-6" id="products_grid">
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr t-ignore="true">
              <td t-foreach="range(0,rows)" t-as="row" t-attf-width="#{100/rows}%"/>
            </tr>
            <tr t-foreach="bins" t-as="tr_product">
              <t t-foreach="tr_product" t-as="td_product">
                <t t-if="td_product">
                  <t t-set="product" t-value="td_product['product']"/>
                  <td t-att-colspan="td_product['x'] != 1 and td_product['x']" t-att-rowspan="td_product['y'] != 1 and td_product['y']" t-attf-class="oe_product oe_grid oe-height-#{td_product['y']*2} #{ td_product['class'] }">
                    <div class="oe_product_cart" t-att-data-publish="product.website_published and 'on' or 'off'">
                      <t t-set="product_image_big" t-value="td_product['x']+td_product['y'] &gt; 2"/>
                      <t t-call="website_sale.products_item"/>
                      <t t-cell="website_sale.products_item"/>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </t>
                <td t-if="not td_product" class="oe-height-2"/>
              </t>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <t t-if="not bins">
          <div class="text-center text-muted oe_product">
            <h3 class="css_editable_display">No product defined.</h3>
            <p groups="sales_team.group_sale_manager">Click 
                                <i>'New'</i> in the top-right corner to create your first product.
                            </p>
          </div>
        </t>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="products_pager">
      <t t-call="website.pager"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add following code where you are displaying your products.

```
<t t-if="td_product.qty_available >= 0">

    executable statement..

</t>
```

Comment: I tried but it gives error saying "Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'qty_available' "

Comment: then try `td_product['qty_available']`

Comment: `<t t-if="product.qty_available &lt;= 0">
                <div class="ribbon-wrapper out-of-stock" style="display: inherit !important;">
                    <div class="ribbon btn btn-danger">Out of Stock</div>
                </div>
                </t>`

I tries this but It woks only when I am logged in as Admin

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you will have issues achieving this from the template as the products on the website are, by default, fetched regardless of their quantity.

Solution will be to do it on the server side: Include `('qty_available','>',0)` in the domain when the website products are being fetched.

For more perfection, [this module](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/15.0/website_hide_by_qty/) seems to handle your feature with more flexibility.